# How to reassign a Pandas dataframe value using the .apply() method?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to reassign values in a pandas dataframe using the .apply() method?

I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'switch': ['ON', 'OFF', 'ON'], 
                   'value': [10, 15, 20]})
print (df, '\n')


def myfunc(row):
    if row['switch']  == 'ON':
        row['value'] = 500
    elif row['switch']  == 'OFF':
        row['value'] = 0

df = df.apply(myfunc, axis=1)
print (df)
```

The code is not working. I am trying to achieve the following output after running the .apply() method:

```
  switch  value
0     ON     500
1    OFF     0
2     ON     500
```

Why is the "row['value'] = 500" assignment not working and how can I rewrite it to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its not working because your function needs to return the value. also, you need to assign it back to the dataframe column for it to be present.

```py
def f(row):
  if row['switch'] == 'ON':
    return 500
  elif row['switch'] == 'OFF':
    return 0
df['value'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

df now has the values:

```
  switch  value
0     ON    500
1    OFF      0
2     ON    500
```

one thing to note here is whether `switch` can have any other values other than `ON` and `OFF`.

- if those are the only permitted values, then you may replace the named function with a lambda expression.
- if other values are present, then they will currently be set to `None` since your if condition block does not handle them. You would need to set a `value` for every type of `switch` or a default value to end up with a data frame without `None` in `value`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to you not returning the value which is causing the error, I would suggest that you do not use `apply()` instead use a vectorized version using `np.where()` which is much faster.

```
import numpy as np

df['value'] = np.where(df['switch'] == "ON", 500, 0)
```